# Law of total probability for random variables with Y < X

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution, integral

Could someone explain to me why the following equation holds?  It is related to the law of total probability , but I don't get it. I'm confused because it's two random variables on the right side and therefore it should also be a joint distribution, right ?

$$\begin{align}
 \int \limits_0^\infty f_X(x) \ \mathbb{P}(Y<x) \ dx
&= \mathbb{P}(Y<X)
\end{align}$$

I understand that
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X \in A, Y \in B) = \int_B f_Y(y) \int_A f_X(x|Y = y) \ dx \ dy .
\end{align}$$

But how do I put this together?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the continuous random variables $W$ and $V$ and their joint distribution $p(w,v)$. By the law of total probability, note that
$$
p(w) = \int p(w,v) \ \text{d}v
$$
and by Bayes' rule
\begin{align}
p(w) &= \int p(w,v) \ \text{d}v \\
&= \int p(w \mid v) \cdot p(v) \ \text{d}v
\end{align}
Going back to your random variables, note that
$$
p(Y < X) = \int p(Y < X \mid x) \cdot p(x) \ \text{d}x
$$
Since $X$ is given in $p(Y < X \mid x)$, then we can let
$$
p(Y < X \mid x) = p(Y < x)
$$
such that
$$
p(Y < X) = \int p(Y < x) \cdot p(x) \ \text{d}x
$$
Another way to see this is to let
$$
Z = 
\begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if} \quad Y < X \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
We are therefore interested in $p(Z = 1)$. By the law of total probability and Bayes' rule,
$$
p(Z = 1) = \int p(Z = 1 \mid x) \cdot p(x) \ \text{d}x
$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! Could you be more specific with the Integral limits? Do you mean integrating x out? Why is it then still a random variable... For example, in your first equations (law of total prob.), we are integrating v out, therefore we get the marginal. But dont hold anymore, by consindering Y < X ?

Comment: Yes we are integrating $v$ out. Not sure what you are asking about...